# How to perform range queries across tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, range

I have two tables in a MySQL database. In the first column of data in table A (A1) I have integer values. In the first and second columns of table B (B1 and B2) I also have integer values. I would like to create a query which would give me the values where A1 is within the range B1 - B2. Is this possible to do with a MySQL query?

Here is an example of what I would like to know how to do:

```
Table A        Table B    
-------        -------    --------
123            12         24
451            450        455
199            202        210
0              499        567
23             5          40
```

The SQL query I am looking for would return the matching A1, B1, and B2 values:

```
451    450     455
23     12      24
23     5       40
```

Comment: Oh, two answers were the same except you didn't include whether the range was inclusive or not. `<` vs `<=`

Comment: Yeah, I assumed inclusive. The between operator is inclusive in MySQL.

Comment: The query should return only if A1 is inclusive within B1-B2.        (ie. `B1 < A1 < B2`)

Comment: That's not "inclusive". Inclusive means including the endpoints, so: B1<=A1<=B2.

Comment: Ok thanks. Thinking about it a bit, I think inclusive is actually what I want. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from a, b where a1 between b1 and b2
```

is as simple as cross joins get. It's the equivalent of an inner join in MySQL and Oracle at least.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I was making it a lot harder than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.A1,
    B.B1,
    B.B2
FROM
    A
INNER JOIN B ON
    B.B1 <= A.A1 AND
    B.B2 >= A.A1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
A.VALUE,
B.VAL_MIN,
B.VAL_MAX
FROM
TAB A,
TAB B
WHERE
A.VALUE >= B.VAL_MIN AND A.VALUE <= B.VAL_MAX
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.A1, b.B1, b.B2 
FROM `Table A` a
    INNER JOIN `Table B` b ON b.B1 < a.A1 AND b.B2 > a.A1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT A.a1,B.b1,B.b2
FROM A,B
WHERE A.a1 >= B.b1
AND A.a1 <= B.b2;
```

Here is the loading of your sample code:

```
use junk
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
CREATE TABLE A (a1 int);
CREATE TABLE B (b1 int,b2 int);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (123),(451),(199),(0),(23);
INSERT INTO B VALUES ( 12, 24),(450,455),(202,210),(499,567),(  5, 40);
SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM B;
SELECT A.a1,B.b1,B.b2
FROM A,B
WHERE A.a1 >= B.b1
AND A.a1 <= B.b2;
```

Here are the results:

```
mysql> use junk
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE A (a1 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE B (b1 int,b2 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO A VALUES (123),(451),(199),(0),(23);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO B VALUES ( 12, 24),(450,455),(202,210),(499,567),(  5, 40);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM A;
+------+
| a1   |
+------+
|  123 |
|  451 |
|  199 |
|    0 |
|   23 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM B;
+------+------+
| b1   | b2   |
+------+------+
|   12 |   24 |
|  450 |  455 |
|  202 |  210 |
|  499 |  567 |
|    5 |   40 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT A.a1,B.b1,B.b2
    -> FROM A,B
    -> WHERE A.a1 >= B.b1
    -> AND A.a1 <= B.b2;
+------+------+------+
| a1   | b1   | b2   |
+------+------+------+
|   23 |   12 |   24 |
|  451 |  450 |  455 |
|   23 |    5 |   40 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```